# parsing serialized Dictionary<string, string> jquery

Tags: c#, asp.net, jquery, json

i've managed to serialze a Dictionary collection. I return it from the webservice to jQuery ajax as a string then i place the return value into the javascript variable that i've declared as an array:

```
var myHistoryList = {};

....
success: function(retVal) {
                    myHistoryList = retVal.d;                   
                }
```

Then I attempt to loop through it, it seems to be not getting the right value. instead its displaying jQuery code like this:

```
trimStart  function(){return this.replace(/^\s+/,"")}
```

which is pretty weird to me.

Heres my javascript for-loop:

```
for (var yahoo in myHistoryList) {
                    $('#myUseTable > tbody:last')
                        .append('<tr><td>' + [yahoo] +
                                '</td><td>' + myHistoryList[yahoo] +
                                '</td>');
                };
```

Help!

Comment: Are you returning JSON, XML, what?  jquery can handle XML and JSON but if it's XML returned you will need to set the dataType of the ajax call to XML, otherwise it defaults to JSON.

Comment: its Json Jeff. the value it returns by the retVal.d is this: "{ 'cow': 'moo', 'cat' : 'meow' }".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery or another library you've included has extended the prototype of `Object` so all objects have extra helper functions included.  You can use the `hasOwnProperty` function in your `for` loop to check for that condition:

```
for (var key in myHistoryList) {
    if (myHistoryList.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        // do your thing
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should also be able to do a for loop like so:

```
for (var i=0; i < myHistoryList.length; i++) {
   alert(myHistoryList[i].SomeProperty);
}
```